# Array Issue with Display Label

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel

Everything appears to be working in this tic tac toe game, except for displaying the "draw" label when there is no winner. The label will switch when Cross or circles wins, but not when there is a tie. 
I'm stumped. E

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    var count = 1
    var activePlayer = 1 //Cross
    var gameState = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    var gameIsActive = true
    let winningCombinations = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [2,4,6]]

    @IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if (gameState[sender.tag-1] == 0 && gameIsActive == true) {
            gameState[sender.tag-1] = activePlayer
            if (activePlayer == 1) {
                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: UIControl.State())
                activePlayer = 2
            } else {
                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "nought.png"), for: UIControl.State())
                activePlayer = 1
            }
        }
        for combination in winningCombinations {
            if gameState[combination[0]] != 0 && 
            gameState[combination[0]] == gameState[combination[1]] && 
            gameState[combination[1]] == gameState[combination[2]] {
                gameIsActive = false
                if gameState[combination[0]] == 1 {
                    label.text = "Cross has won!"
                } else {
                    label.text = "Circle has won!"
                }
                if gameIsActive == true {
                    for i in gameState {
                        count = i*count
                    }
                    if count != 0 {
                        label.text = "It was a draw."
                        label.isHidden = false
                        playAgainButton.isHidden = false
                    }
                }
                playAgainButton.isHidden = false
                label.isHidden = false
            }
        } 
    } // End Button Action

    @IBOutlet weak var playAgainButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func playAgain(_ sender: Any) {
        gameState = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        gameIsActive = true
        activePlayer = 1
        playAgainButton.isHidden = true
        label.isHidden = true

        for i in 1...9 {
            let button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
            button.setImage(nil, for: UIControl.State())
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        playAgainButton.isHidden = true
        label.isHidden = true
    }
} // End ViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saying

```
            gameIsActive = false
            // ... some other stuff ...
            if gameIsActive == true {
                // check for a draw
            }
```

But `gameIsActive` is *not* true, because you just set it to false. Therefore we never perform the check for a draw.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone! I finally got it working correctly.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var playAgainButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
var count = 1
var activePlayer = 1 //Cross
var gameState = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
var gameIsActive = true
let winningCombinations = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [2,4,6]]


@IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject) {

count = 1;
if (gameState[sender.tag-1] == 0 && gameIsActive == true) {

if (activePlayer == 1) {
    gameState[sender.tag-1] = activePlayer
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: UIControl.State())
    activePlayer = 2

} else {

    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "nought.png"), for: UIControl.State())
    gameState[sender.tag-1] = activePlayer
    activePlayer = 1

        }
}

for combination in winningCombinations {
if gameState[combination[0]] != 0 && gameState[combination[0]] ==
    gameState[combination[1]] && gameState[combination[1]] ==
    gameState[combination[2]]{
    gameIsActive = false

if gameState[combination[0]] == 1 {
    label.text = "Cross has won!"
} else {
    label.text = "Circle has won!"
}
    playAgainButton.isHidden = false
    label.isHidden = false
}
```

}

```
if gameIsActive == true{
    for i in gameState{
        count = i * count
    }
    if count != 0{
        label.text = "DRAW!"
    playAgainButton.isHidden = false
    label.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

}

```
@IBAction func playAgain(_ sender: Any) {

gameState = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    gameIsActive = true
    activePlayer = 1
    playAgainButton.isHidden = true
    label.isHidden = true

for i in 1...9
{
    let button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
    button.setImage(nil, for: UIControl.State())
}
```

}

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    playAgainButton.isHidden = true
    label.isHidden = true
}
```

}